PDDL Planning Service returned code 400 BAD REQUEST
When running the planner it came up this error. The strange part is that when I run the same code in edit.planning.domain I get no trouble. I red a similar question from someone else where it has been suggested that the problem could be in plugin configuration. Just explain me where do I get it and I share it. Thanks.
I didn't try anything. I have just checked the sintaxes and they seem to be ok.
